# Importing a javascript file in another file and compiling using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

To run my practice JS files I have used Node so for example I say `node bts.js` .
I needed a `queue` data structure so I installed Collections using `npm install collections --save` and also seen in picture it does show in the hierarchy.

Then in my JS file I said `const Deque = require('./collections/deque');`
and then later I wanted to use it like `const dq = new Deque();`
but I get the **'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'** error.
But why?
I have attached the screen shot if my structure too.

[image]

Comment: As is stated in the [docs](http://www.collectionsjs.com/deque), you need: `var Deque = require("collections/deque");` (since collections is a module, not a script in your main folder)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to import an external module (installed in `node_modules`) with a relative path - `./collections/deque`. This will look in local folder in your source code named `collections` and try to find a file named `deque.js` inside of it. Since it does not exist, you get the `module not found` error.

You have to import the dependency from `node_moduels` as:

```js
const Deque = require("collections/deque"); // see the missing ./ at the start of the path
```